# how to create kotlin class when developing intellij idea plugin?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, kotlin, intellij-plugin

When developing **Intellij Idea** plugin creating **java** classes can be done with `JavaDirectoryService` which creates `PsiClasses` according to file templates. Is there any way to create **kotlin** classes with similar method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FileTemplateUtil.createFromTemplate()` to create a file of any type from a template, including a Kotlin class.

```
val fileTemplate = FileTemplateManager.getInstance().getTemplate("Kotlin Class")
FileTemplateUtil.createFromTemplate(template, fileName, null, psiDirectory)
```

Comment: Can you give us one implementation of `FileTemplateUtil.createFromTemplate()` method to create one basic kotlin class? There is not much resources about it, Thank you in advance.

Comment: See edited answer. I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you did lot for me))